# Problem with the controllers running PR2 on gazebo

Tags: microcontroller, gazebo, pr2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, i'm working on ros electric the [PR2 tutorials](http://ros.org/wiki/pr2_mechanism/Tutorials/Running%20a%20realtime%20joint%20controller) and everything works OK, but the PR2 robot doesn't move i try with other examples like moving the shadow robot but i dont have succes.
When i did the `rxgraph` the topic of the controller  does not published anything in the gazebo.

I think that the problem is with gazebo because the controllers works really fine, i don't know if i need to install some stack or package for this or what happen..

Anyone has an idea??

Thank you!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54669/problem-with-the-controllers-running-pr2-on-gazebo/) by [joseescobar60](https://answers.ros.org/users/3496/joseescobar60/) on ROS Answers with karma: 172 on 2013-02-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had similar problem. What I found is that you have to switch off the controller that is already assigned to joint you are trying to control. They don't explicitly tell you that in tutorial but it is a must.

---

Originally posted by [IgorZ](https://answers.ros.org/users/4123/igorz/) with karma: 86 on 2013-02-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joseescobar60](https://answers.ros.org/users/3496/joseescobar60/) on 2013-02-11**:
hello, do you know how to do it??